# react component module is not rendering in its own directory when npm start

Tags: reactjs, webpack

**TLDR: npm start is not rendering component**

So im sort of confused on the folder structure when it comes to developing a distributable react component.

I want to be able to demo my module within the module directory itself as well as being able to distribute the component in another application.

This is my current directory

[image]

Currently npm start gives me this

[image]

this is my webpack config

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2' // u sorta need this

  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,

        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|build)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { 
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/react'],
            plugins:['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
//  public directory will render the component.
  devServer: {
    contentBase: __dirname  + './dist',
    compress: true,
    port: 9000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    progress: true
  },

};
```

dist/index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Fetch from '../src';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Fetch/>
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

 </body>
</html>
```

and **src/index.js**

```
import Fetch from './Fetch';

export default Fetch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use storybooks for demo and document your reusable components . better approach is to have stories at component level by adding .stories.js file to your each components .

checkout : https://storybook.js.org/.

For folder structure you can start with create-react-app which gives you all the features you need to build, run and test .

checkout : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: thanks but this give me a solution . but thanks anyway.

Comment: are you looking out to build a react component library and to share the component across your different products @BARNOWL

Comment: yes, right now i can install this on another application and i can use it, however i want to npm start this module within the directory itself. You know what i mean ?

Comment: why do you want to do npm start in the module ? To view that particular component rendered for demo ?